# Value of $ \cos 52^{\circ} + \cos 68^{\circ} + \cos 172^{\circ} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am a little weak in trigonometry. I have two questions:

1. Find the value of $\cos 52^{\circ} + \cos 68^{\circ} + \cos 172^{\circ} $
2. Find the value of $\sin 28^{\circ}+ \cos 17^{\circ} + \cos 28^{\circ} + \sin 17^{\circ} $

I am asking these questions because:
1. I am weak and unable to solve these.
2. I want to know the difference in these questions.

Comment: check the validity of $\#2$ as there are two $\cos17^\circ$

Comment: @PeterPhipps What was your reasoning for removing the degree signs out of the numbers? It is actually necessary to show the degree signs here as otherwise the numbers would mean radians.

Comment: @mathh, yes, I noticed that. Our edits were quite close together timewise. When I clicked Edit, it was the original version I was changing. I did not deliberately undo any of your edits because they weren't there then. Perhaps I took too long to edit; by the time I clicked Save, you must have already saved yours. Then my Save overwrote your changes. But I didn't get the "there is already an edit in progress" message: the system let my changes stand. I wouldn't remove another user's edits (unless it was my own post). It looks like a software glitch.

Comment: @bhatacharjee, cos to sin edited, it was a mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that,
$$
\cos(\alpha\pm \beta)=\cos \alpha\cos \beta\mp\sin \alpha\sin \beta
$$
and
$$
\cos(180^\circ-\alpha)=-\cos\alpha.
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{align}
\cos52^\circ+\cos68^\circ+\cos172^\circ&=\color{blue}{\cos(60^\circ-8^\circ)+\cos(60^\circ+8^\circ)}+\color{red}{\cos(180^\circ-8^\circ)}\\
&=\color{blue}{2\cos60^\circ\cos8^\circ}+(\color{red}{-\cos8^\circ})\\
&=\color{blue}{2\cdot\frac12\cdot\cos8^\circ}-\color{red}{\cos8^\circ}\\
&=0.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Have you noticed my answer?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Nope. I use my tab to answer this question. Sorry, I didn't see yours.

Comment: Please, do not get me wrong @labbhattacharjee. It takes time for a tab to reload & update the page. When I saw this question, I didn't immediately answer it because there was something I had to do.

Comment: Hope you understand my point. Nothing wrong if restating helps

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I do. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)

$$\cos52^\circ+\cos68^\circ=2\cos60^\circ\cos8^\circ$$

Alternatively, $\displaystyle52=60-8,68=60+8\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)=?$

and $$\cos172^\circ=\cos(180^\circ-8^\circ)=-\cos8^\circ$$

Comment: Uh why do you write the complete unpronounceable names of the formulas. my tongue twists.

Comment: @Tim, This nomenclature is not owned by me:)

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $$\cos3(\underbrace{60^\circ-x})=\cos(180^\circ-3x)=-\cos3x$$

and  $$\cos3(\underbrace{60^\circ+x})=\cos(180^\circ+3x)=-\cos3x$$

and  $$\cos3(\underbrace{180^\circ-x})=\cos(360^\circ+180^\circ-3x)=\cos(180^\circ-3x)=-\cos3x$$

As $\displaystyle\cos3x=4\cos^3x-3\cos x,$

and as $\displaystyle-\cos3x=\cos(180^\circ-3x)=\cos(180^\circ+3x)=\cos3(180^\circ-x)$

the roots of $\displaystyle4\cos^3y-3\cos y=-\cos3x\iff4\cos^3y-3\cos y+\cos3x=0$

will be  $\displaystyle\cos(60^\circ-x),\cos(60^\circ+x),\cos(180^\circ-x)$ (no two are in general same, right?)

Using Vieta's formula $\displaystyle\cos(60^\circ-x)+\cos(60^\circ+x)+\cos(180^\circ-x)=\frac04$

Here $\displaystyle x=8^\circ$

Comment: @Vivek, How about this? Could you solve the second problem?

Comment: Tried to understand, but it seems its too hard for me (as I stated I am weak in Trigonometery)...thanks anyway, your previous answer was helpful! :)